# Gathering a sequence of unknown length in dask

Tags: python, dask

I would like to implement a parallel optimization algorithm using dask. My goals are:

- The main optimization loop should run on a worker.
- The number of optimization steps is not known in advance, and the optimization step must spawn other tasks.
- The intermediate results should be auditable, so that I can monitor what is happening.

An example code that satisfies all the above criteria is:

```py
from time import sleep
from distributed import Client, get_client


def f(x):
    sleep(0.5)
    return (x - 1)**3


def derivative(x):
    sleep(1)
    return 3 * (x - 1)**2


def newton_optimization(x, fval, dfdx):
    if abs(fval) < 1e-10:
        return x, None
    x = x - fval / dfdx
    client = get_client()
    fval = client.submit(f, x)
    dfdx = client.submit(derivative, x)
    next_step = client.submit(newton_optimization, x, fval, dfdx)
    return x, next_step


client = Client()
task = client.submit(newton_optimization, 0, 1, 3)

while task is not None:
    i, task = task.result()
    print(i)

client.shutdown()
```

However it doesn't feel elegant for example because in order to check the current state of the optimization, I need to follow the result chain all the way from the start. Is there a better way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe you can use [Queue](https://docs.dask.org/en/latest/futures.html#queues) or some other [coordination primitive](https://docs.dask.org/en/latest/futures.html#coordination-primitives) to keep track of intermediates.

Also, based on [these Dask docs](https://distributed.dask.org/en/stable/task-launch.html#launch-tasks-from-tasks), using the `worker_client()` context manager here will be more stable.

So, it'll be something like:

```py
from distributed import worker_client, Queue

def newton_optimization(x, fval, dfdx):
    if abs(fval) < 1e-10:
        return x
    with worker_client() as client:
        x = x - fval / dfdx
        fval = client.submit(f, x)
        dfdx = client.submit(derivative, x)
        next_step = client.submit(newton_optimization, x, fval, dfdx)
        queue.put(next_step)
    return x

queue = Queue()

while True:
    future = queue.get()
    print(future.result())
```

Note that it's usually best to avoid launching tasks from tasks because it may cause reliability issues. That said, it looks like your workflow needs this, so I'll just share that this feature is well supported in Dask (even though the docs say it's experimental -- the docs need to be updated) but do expect some nuances here. :)

Thank you for asking this question, it helped start a good discussion here: https://github.com/dask/distributed/issues/5671

Comment: Thanks! The proposed redesign seems really powerful and at the same time nice to use.

Answer (score 0):

A quick solution is to use [adaptive](https://github.com/python-adaptive/adaptive), which sounds a lot like what you are interested in and has very cool visualisation of progress. (update: oops, just noticed that there is a contributor to adaptive with the same name as yours, so there is a good chance you know about this package.)

Some suggestions on your code:

- right now the computation is serial: the while loop blocks until each `task` is computed (due to `.result`). A somewhat better way might be to use `.map` to submit multiple values for evaluation.

```py
from dask.distributed import as_completed

# use context manager to avoid .shutdown
with Client() as client:

    # submit multiple values with .map
    # the sample values might need to be chosen with care for better efficiency
    tasks = client.map(newton_optimization, [0, 0.1, 0.2], [1, 1.1, 1.2], [3, 3.1, 3.2]) 

    # add to the task list as new tasks are spawned
    for task in as_completed(tasks):
        if task is not None:
            tasks.append(task.result()[1]) # this could be refactored
```

- multiple starting points might converge at some point, so to reduce the number of very similar values being evaluated, it might be acceptable to incorporate some rounding when generating a new task, e.g. if you have multiple tasks that are evaluating values that differ by `1e-5` then adding `np.round(x, 1e-5)`might reduce the number of parallel computations once the tolerable accuracy has been reached.

Comment: I'm one of the authors of adaptive, so thanks! :) My main question however is how to offload the main loop onto a worker. Your answer doesn't address that.

Comment: Yes, I noticed it after submitting the answer... :) could you elaborate how what you are looking to do is not solved by adaptive?

Comment: I want to understand the best practices in offloading the main loop to a worker.